# Power BI date range custom column for filter

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

I have a calendar table in Power BI linked to two other tables, one with occupancy by date and another with predicted occupancy by date.  The second table goes well into the future.

I want the report to have a rolling 15 day range, 7 days prior to today and 7 days into the future.  I tried to create a custom column using:

ReportRange = IF(DATESBETWEEN (Calendar[SQL_Date], (TODAY()-7), (TODAY()+7)),1,0)

I get a response "No syntax errors have been detected."
[image: No syntax error]

But when I click "OK", I get a yellow bar/warning:
"Expression.Error: The name 'IF' wasn't recognized.  Make sure it's spelled correctly."

Can anyone help with this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write custom columns in the query editor in [M code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/date-functions), not DAX.

Something like this may work:

```
if Date.IsInPreviousNDays([SQL_Date], 7) and Date.IsInNextNDays([SQL_Date], 7)
then 1
else 0
```

You may prefer to use [relative date filtering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/desktop-slicer-filter-date-range) instead though.

Comment: Yes, this was the approach that worked...at least for me!     if Number.From(DateTime.FixedLocalNow() - [SQL_Date]) >= -7
and Number.From(DateTime.FixedLocalNow() - [SQL_Date]) <= 7
then 1 else 0

Comment: I didn't write it quite like I intended. I've updated the answer but your approach looks reasonable too.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to use a PowerQuery M Language column through the custom column editor. This will not work in M. You will need to create a measure in DAX to do the calculation.

In your DAX you can use DatesBetween, [as per this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/datesbetween-function-dax):

```
=CALCULATE(SUM(InternetSales_USD[SalesAmount_USD]), DATESBETWEEN(DateTime[DateKey],  
    DATE(2007,6,1),  
    DATE(2007,8,31)  
  ))
```

You can use the [TODAY keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/today-function-dax) to work calculations off the current date.

[image]

Comment: I put this in a New Measure: ReportRange = DATESBETWEEN (Calendar[SQL_Date], (TODAY()-7), (TODAY()+7))

Comment: No error but can't use it to limit report date range.

Comment: You will need to use it as part of a measure, I dont have the exact syntax to hand but something like: Last Week Total = CALCULATE(SUM([MyTable.Cost]), ALL(Dates), DATESBETWEEN(Today, Today - 7))

Answer (score 0):

for "rolling" filters i found it very useful to build generic offset columns for day/week/month/quarter into your date table. with that you can easy filter a visual e.g. with "week offset" > 1 and "week offset" <-1 to get rolling 2 weeks views... Detailed howto can be find here: https://radacad.com/offset-columns-for-the-date-table-flexibility-in-relative-date-filtering-for-power-bi

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to filter the data coming in to the report, you can use a filter.

You can do this in the Advanced Editor, sample below.

```
let
    Source = BillingData,
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(Source,{"Date"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Other Columns",{{"Date", type date}}),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Changed Type"),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Duplicates", each Date.IsInPreviousNDays(Date.AddDays(DateTime.LocalNow(), 7), 14))
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```

I started with the standard date filter and customised it using the advanced editor to add 7 days and then subtract 14.

[image]